# create new column from conditional statement without mask pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a better way to do the following:

```
                 A      
 TRDNumber      
ALB2008081610   430     
ALB200808167    0       
ALB200808168    190
```

Creating a new column based on the value in another column using a conditional statement

```
                 A      B
 TRDNumber      
ALB2008081610   430     z
ALB200808167    0       x
ALB200808168    190     y
```

The following code works but I know that there must be a better way to do this.

```
mask = df['A'] == 0
df20 = df[mask] 
df20['B'] = 'x'
df20

mask2 = ((df.A != 0) & (df.B <= 200) )
df21 = df[mask2] 
df21['B'] = 'y'
df21

pieces = [df20,df21]
pd.concat(pieces)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do the following:

```
#%%
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = pd.Series([430,0,190], index=['ALB2008081610', 'ALB200808167', 'ALB200808168'])
print(df)
#%%
df['B'] = None
print(df)

#%%
df.loc[(df.A==0), 'B'] = 'x'
print(df)

#%%
df.loc[(df.A!=0) & (df.A<=200), 'B'] = 'y'
print(df)
```

An explanation about indexing can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Tip for next time: provide the code for creating the dataframe. Then we can directly play around with the same dataframe you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can create function and `apply` it to your dataset:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     if x['A'] == 0:
...         return 'x'
...     elif x['A'] < 200:
...         return 'y'
...     else:
...         return 'z'
... 
>>> df['B'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
>>> df
                 A  B
TRDNumber            
ALB2008081610  430  z
ALB200808167     0  x
ALB200808168   190  y
```